# When I resize my website the webpage doesn't fit in well

Tags: html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

[my webpage at 595px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPXNP.png)

I'm using HTML, SASS & Bootstrap for the website. I've included the source code of the hero section. It worked perfectly fine until I started to look at the responsiveness. The webpage seems to get smaller than the actual screen size. You can check the screenshots

My HTML:

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Restora</title>

    <!-- Google Fonts -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Medula+One&family=Roboto:wght@300&family=Teko:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">

    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/0df7cc894a.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>

    <div class="hero-section">

        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Restora</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
          
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
              <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Menu</a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
                  </li>

                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link " href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
              </ul>

              <ul class="icons">
                <i class="fa fa-search fa-2x"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-cart-plus fa-2x"></i>
              </ul>

            </div>
          </nav>


              <div class="container-fluid">
                  <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-12 hero-img">
                      <img src="./restora-bg.png" alt="">
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-12 hero-text">
                        <h1> <span>Experience</span> <br> The Real Taste</h1>
                        <div class="line"></div>
                        <p class="lead">Delicious Food For Every Mood</p>

                        <button>Order Now</button>
                    </div>

                  </div>
              </div>

    </div>
```

My CSS:

```
      body {
        font-family: 'Teko', sans-serif;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
        // Navbar

    .hero-section {
        nav {
            padding: 0 50px;


            a {
                font-size: 24px;
                font-family: roboto, sans-serif;
                letter-spacing: 1px;
                font-weight: 500;
            }
        
            li {
                padding: 0 10px;
            }

            .navbar-brand {
                font-size: 48px;
                font-family: 'Medula One', cursive;
            }

            .icons {
                padding-top: 15px;
            }
        }
    }

    // Hero-Section

    .hero-section {
        letter-spacing: 8px;

        .hero-img {
            // background: url('restora-bg.png') no-repeat;
            // background-size: contain;

            width: 100%;
        }

        .hero-text {
            padding: 100px 80px;
            
            @media(max-width: 768px) {
                padding: 10px;
            }

            h1 {
                font-size: 6rem;
                @media(max-width: 768px) {
                    font-size: 4rem;
                }

            }

            span {
                font-size: 8rem;
                font-weight: bold;

                @media(max-width: 768px) {
                    font-size: 6rem;
                }
            }

            p {
                font-size: 2rem;
                padding-top: 30px;
                letter-spacing: 2px;
                font-family: roboto, sans-serif;
            }
            
            button {
                font-size: 1.3rem;
                font-weight: 600;
                padding: 8px 20px;
                letter-spacing: 2px;
                font-family: roboto, sans-serif;
                background-color: white;
                border: 3px solid;

                &:hover {
                    border: 2px solid black;
                    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
                    color: white;
                }
            }

            .line {
                background-color: rgb(146, 1, 1);
                width: 100px;
                height: 5px

            }
        }
    }
```

The website is fitting well up to the screen width gets to 600px. But when I lower the screen size more, the webpage seems to get more and more smaller than the actual screen size.

I've used several methods like using max-width on the image, checking the viewport, using different properties to html & body tags to fill the screen size etc.

Please take some time to help me fix it.

[my webpage at 496px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trv33.png)

Comment: is there a device that has a viewport of less than 366px?

Comment: Please, upload the *entire* code so we can scan it for the source of the problem.

Comment: Alright, I've added the source code and updated the screenshots. Help for fixing this would be really appreciated.

Comment: Lelio Faieta, actually Motorola Moto G4 and Galaxy Fold have less than 366px, so I guess there would be more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Hey Akib,
The solution looks simple if I'm not wrong, as you've included bootstrap in your project so, just add "img-fluid" or "w-100" class to your img tag.

```
<img src="./restora-bg.png" class="img-fluid" alt="">
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the image which is causing the problem. By default, images are able to span a width wider than the page.

If you add:

```
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

To the css, it should fix this.

Comment: Yes I've tried that, I've actually added the full source code. Could you please help me out, maybe something's missing or I'm doing it in the wrong way

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue with the image, Try to give it `w-100` class
OR try to remove it via the inspector and see if it causing the issue or not

Answer (score 0):

Is it maybe the nav that's being resized?